# on nvidia gpu, does __hmul use fp32 core?

Tags: cuda

Refer to https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-hopper-architecture-in-depth/
, each SM has three type cuda cores, e.g int32 core/fp32 core/fp64 core. If the datatype is int32/fp32/fp64, I think the instruction will be issued to the int32/fp32/fp64 core respectively.

But, how about the half datatype, for example, `__hmul` or `__hmul2`.
Do they use fp32 core to compute? If so, can someone explain how it works.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my (limited) knowledge - **We don't know for certain** what computes FP16 multiplication operations on NVIDIA GPUs.

This is because NVIDIA is generally rather tight-lipped about what its hardware actually is. It prefers marketing terms (like "CUDA cores" - which aren't actually cores). It's *possible* that  that the Hopper SM diagram (below) actually represents physical hardware, but it's also possible it's just a convenient conceptualization. We don't know whether there really are 4-sub-SM's, or just the ability to schedule 4 warps per clock cycle; we don't know the "tensor cores" really are disjoint hardware; and we don't know what hardware handles half-precision arithmetic: FP32 functional units? The "tensor cores", in a degenerated operation mode? Something else?

The point is, that you have to engage in "lawyerly reading" of NVIDIA's publications. They commit to what they explicitly commit, and you need to strip away the implicit assumptions they encourage you to make. So, you don't quite know what's in the box - you do know the tables, like that of the number of instructions the SM can retire per cycle - and you design and write code based on that. And on a lot of testing and profiling of course.

[image]

Note: Just to be clear - I think this is inappropriate behavior on NVIDIA's part. It *should* tell its customers, and the scientific/engineering communities, what kind of hardware it actually has; and should not try to derive benefit of some sort from keeping us in the dark.

Comment: (+1) for emphasizing the futility of speculating about GPU hardware internals. It is certainly possible to design a wider multiplier so it also supports vectors of narrower multiplies. One can search the literature for "floating point multiplier" plus "SIMD mode" or "vector mode" to find examples of such designs. We do not know whether NVIDIA uses such a design or not, and to a CUDA programmer it arguably should not matter.

Comment: I'd say it does matter to the programmer. For example, when you need to speculate regarding what happens when you do _both_ FP32 and FP16 work: If that's done on differnet physical units, then you can expect to benefit from something close to the sum of throughputs; but if it's all done on FP32 units, then you'll get the maximum of throughputs, or even the minimum of  both throughputs. You just have to contend with that being trial-and-error, plus changes between u-architectures.

Comment: @njuffa: I didn't say I was making an argument vis-a-vis the management of NVIDIA, I'm just saying that it does matter objectively. And - IMHO it's not sufficient for 99% of programmers (unless you count those who don't actually write device code but use libraries and frameworks with the occasional lambda).

Comment: "Generally speaking I do not understand why people keep asking processor architecture questions on SO. Seems off-topic to me. " <- Completely disagree on that one. Whether it's physical or conceptual architecture - the conception of the hardware is important for orientation when writing the code targeting it; is also important for understanding confusing behavior in one's programs; and finally is important to setting expectations or hopes regarding the potential of using this functionality or the other.

Comment: We have performance metrics for certain pipelines, which give a hint for the functional unit used. It is still possible that the same pipeline leads to different functional units or that different pipelines end in the same functional unit later on.

Answer (score 2):

On both Ampere and Hopper the int32 cores do integer and the fp32 core do floating point operations, allowing for simultaneous executing of integer and floating point instructions. (see the [Turing tuning guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/turing-tuning-guide/index.html)). The hmul instruction is processed on the fp32 cores. This can be seen section 8.4.1 (page 144) of the [Cuda C++ programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf).  A total of 256 fp16 instructions can be retired per multiprocessor (SM) per cycle. Whereas 128 fp32 can be retired per cycle as well as 128 int32 instructions.

Because the number of int32 instructions is the same as fp32 instructions, each must have its own dedicated core. The dedicated int32 and fp32 cores were introduced in Volta.

Each fp32 core executes two fp16 instructions in parallel.
This is backed up by the following comment on page 146. Which says that fp16 needs to be packed into a 32bit half2 data structure before performing instructions.

> In order to achieve good performance for 16-bit precision
> floating-point add, multiply or multiply-add, it is recommended that
> the half2 datatype is used for half precision and __nv_bfloat162 be
> used for __nv_bfloat16 precision. Vector intrinsics (for example,
> __hadd2, __hsub2, __hmul2, __hfma2) can then be used to do two operations in a single instruction. Using half2 or __nv_bfloat162 in
> place of two calls using half or __nv_bfloat16 may also help
> performance of other intrinsics, such as warp shuffles.
>
> The intrinsic __halves2half2 is provided to convert two half precision
> values to the half2 datatype.
>
> The intrinsic __halves2bfloat162 is provided to convert two
> __nv_bfloat precision values to the __nv_bfloat162 datatype.

On page 448 of the same document it is mentioned that matrix manipulations are handled by the tensor cores, but these cores only operate on matrices, not on a per instruction basis.

Comment: Hi, @Johan, thanks for you answer. As you said, __hmul2 can do two half data operation in a single instruction, so the fp16 tflops performance  is twice as much as fp32, right? If so, the __hmul only do one data operation in a single instruction, and it only use the half part of fp32 core. In this case,  the performance of __hmul is the same as fmul, which means __hmul instruction will not bring any speedup effect compare to fmul, is my understanding correct？

Comment: @irasin You need to pack 2 fp16 into a 32-bit half2 structure and then perform the mul on the half2 structure. This will perform two multiplications on a single lane (thread) in your warp. If you just perform hmul instructions on a lone fp16, then it will not work any faster.

Comment: FWIW/nitpick, I don't think this answer has supported this statement: "The hmul instruction is processed on the fp32 cores.".  It might be, I don't happen to know, but the supposed justification based on p144 of the programming guide is meaningless.  Just because you found two numbers in that table that happen to be the same throughput in terms of ops/clk, does not mean that those 2 instruction types are processed in the same functional unit.  Counter example: cc8.0 (ampere A100/A30) has a throughput of 256 fp16/clk but 64 fp32/clk.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, see footnote 3 for cc8.0: `128 for __nv_bfloat16`

Comment: how does that change anything I said? Are you saying that there is not a throughtput of 256 for fp16?  fp16 and bfloat16 are not the same thing.  hmul and hmul2 operate on both [half](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__ARITHMETIC.html#group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__ARITHMETIC_1g864da184fc3f0cd0bf3860980857f18c), which is fp16, and [bfloat16](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____BFLOAT16__ARITHMETIC.html#group__CUDA__MATH____BFLOAT16__ARITHMETIC_1g6ac94552f8a8526c8ad58b3017d7382b).

Answer (score 2):

See [Nsight Compute Kernel Profiling Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/index.html#metrics-decoder) Metrics Guide > Metrics Decoder > Pipelines table.

> - **fma** Fused Multiply Add/Accumulate.    The FMA pipeline processes most FP32 arithmetic (FADD, FMUL, FMAD).    It also performs integer
>   multiplication operations (IMUL, IMAD), as    well as integer dot
>   products. On GA10x, FMA is a logical pipeline    that indicates peak
>   FP32 and FP16x2 performance. It is composed of    the FMAHeavy and
>   FMALite physical pipelines.
> - **fmaheavy** Fused Multiply Add/Accumulate Heavy. FMAHeavy performs FP32 arithmetic (FADD, FMUL, FMAD), FP16 arithmetic (HADD2, HMUL2,
>   HFMA2), and integer dot products.
> - **fmalite** Fused Multiply Add/Accumulate Lite. FMALite performs FP32 arithmetic (FADD, FMUL, FMA) and FP16 arithmetic (HADD2, HMUL2, HFMA2).
> - **fp16** Half-precision floating-point. On Volta, Turing and NVIDIA GA100, the FP16 pipeline performs paired FP16 instructions (FP16x2).
>   It also contains a fast FP32-to-FP16 and FP16-to-FP32 converter.
>   Starting with GA10x chips, this functionality is part of the FMA
>   pipeline.

On GA10x+ the input vector for the H*2 instruction is split and simultaneously dispatched to both the fmalite and fmaheavy pipes.

On GA10x+

- fmaheavy pipe executes integer multiply operations (IMUL, IMAD).
- fp16x2 (H*2) vectors are split and simultaneously dispatched to both the fmalite and fmaheavy pipes.